# @XmlElement is null when it has no namespace

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm using Jaxb unmarshaller to map some part of response from xmpp server to java object.

Test.java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MucUser.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream((
            "<x xmlns='http://jabber.org/prot" +
            "ocol/muc#user'><item role='moderator'" +
            " affiliation='owner'/></x>").getBytes());
        MucUser mucUser = (MucUser) unmarshaller.unmarshal(bais);
        System.out.println(mucUser.getItem());
    }
}
```

MucUser.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user", name = "x")
public class MucUser {
    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    private Item item;

    // getter and setter without annotations
}
```

Item.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "role")
    private String role;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "affiliation")
    private String affiliation;

    // getters and setters without annotations
}
```

I don't use ObjectFactory.java and package-info.java. Field `item` is not getting unmarshalled, and `mucUser.getItem()` returns null. But when I explicitly add namespace `tst` to element `<item>` in Test.java and modify MucUser.java to use annotation `@XmlElement(name = "item", namespace="tst")` it works fine!

However, I can not modify that string by my will, it's a part of protocol.

How should I properly map `item` in my MucUser class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML you are setting the default namespace in the 'x' element. Contained elements use this namespace. Item should therefore use the same namespace as Mcuser

Comment: Thank you. I modified annotation in ```MucUser.java``` to ```@XmlElement(name = "item", namespace = "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user")``` and it started to work as expected.